# IndexOutofRangeException :There is no row at position 0

Tags: c#, .net, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to design a mini project of a quiz application using resource bundle. I get an error of `There is no row at position 0` when I insert the following `if` condition. Where I am catching the string from combobox in variable `X`.

```
SampleResourceBundle.Loginpage l = new SampleResourceBundle.Loginpage();
if(l.x.Equals("mr_IN"))
   sql = "select * from quesans where qid>48";
else if (l.x.Equals("en_US"))
   sql = "select * from quesans where qid<48";
```

The error is given in the following statement in the method from the next form:

```
textBox1.Text = ds.Tables["QA"].Rows[recno].ItemArray[2].ToString();
```

But if I remove the `if` statement the code executes perfectly fine.

Comment: There are *no rows*, which is why the first row (at position 0) is Out-Of-Range.

Comment: Without the if statement it is executing and i am getting the correct output for both the queries. @user2864740

Comment: What's the value of l.x ? Why are you using equals instead of ==? Did you check if your if statement is culture, case sensitive relevant?

Comment: @user3259776 Then your if statement changes something (ie. maybe there are rows for qid>48, but not qid<48?). Again, there are *no rows* when that exception is thrown.

Comment: @RandRandom 'l' is the object of my LoginPage class and in the variable "x" I am storing the value from the Combo Box. Since I am using it to check the contents of a string I have used Equals().[I tried == also but it did not work]. So basically if x has en_US language I want only the English questions displayed else if x has mr_IN i want the Marathi questions displayed from the database.

Comment: What's the type if x? And what's the VALUE when you look at the debug session?

Comment: @RandRandom I had made a ridiculous mistake of taking string values "en_US" instead of "en-US". Thus it returned null values. The code works fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no rows in `ds.Tables["QA"]`.

You need to check if there is a row you want to read before attempting it:

```
if (recno < ds.Tables["QA"].Rows.Count)
    textBox1.Text = ds.Tables["QA"].Rows[recno].ItemArray[2].ToString();
```

Comment: If i execute both the queries separately without the "if" statement they work fine. "If" is causing the indexoutofrange exception.

Comment: Both `if`s may be false. What is the value of `sql` in this case?

Comment: Yes I think it's not getting any value from the if statement, because I tried to display the value of "x" with "MessageBox.show(l.x)" and did not get it on the form. Well if i execute the query without "if" its fetching all the question and answers from the database correctly in variable "sql" and displays it on the form.

Comment: There problem is somewhere in a part of the code you haven't posted. I'll leave my answer with only the check recommendation for now.

Comment: I had made a simple and ridiculous mistake of taking string values "en_US" instead of "en-US". The code works fine. Thank you for the help.